# Packages installed using poetry are not available inside `poetry shell`

Tags: python, python-venv, python-poetry

Packages installed using `poetry install` are available in `poetry run` but not in `poetry shell`.

```bash
$ poetry add {package}
$ poetry install
```

```bash
# this works
$ poetry run python
> import {package}
```

```bash
# ...but not this
$ poetry shell
$ python
> import {package}
```

Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding what `poetry shell` does?
I thought it would activate the virtual environment setup by poetry.
`poetry --version` prints `Poetry (version 1.5.1)`

Comment: What does `type python` output inside `poetry shell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Brian61354270's comment, I checked the Python executable that was being used inside `poetry shell` using `type python`. Turns out it was pyenv that was overriding the python path whenever I open a new shell. I was able to fix this problem by removing the pyenv config file and letting poetry control the Python version.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your frustration, it should work.

What I think you should do:

1. `$ deactivate` (in case you are still in poetry shell)
2. delete manually the poetry ".venv" folder (I suppose you have set "virtualenvs.in-project to true)
3. delete manually the .lock file (I assume that your pyproject.toml is up-to-date with the packages you want to import)
4. `$ poetry self update`

Then, reinstall everything.

1. `$ poetry install`
2. `$ poetry shell`
3. `$ python`
4. `> import *your_package*`

Hope that helps,